# For each control variable must be variant

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ConsolidateData()
    Dim MasterWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim SheetName As Range
    
    Set MasterWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Initialize the next row in the master worksheet
    NextRow = 2 ' Start from row 2 (assuming headers in row 1)
    
    
    Dim SheetNames() As String
    SheetNames = Array("STD", "RUSH", "AIR", "SMD", "PANTRY")
    
   
    For Each SheetName In SheetNames
        Filename = Dir("C:\Path\To\Your\Workbooks\" & "EOD*.xlsx") 
        
        Do While Filename <> ""
           
            Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\To\Your\Workbooks\" & Filename) ' Change the path as needed
            
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set SourceWorksheet = SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If Not SourceWorksheet Is Nothing Then
                
                LastRow = SourceWorksheet.Cells(SourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                
                SourceWorksheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy MasterWorkbook.Sheets("ConsolidatedData").Cells(NextRow, 1) 
                
               
                NextRow = NextRow + (LastRow - 1)
            End If
            
          
            SourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
          
            Filename = Dir
        Loop
    Next SheetName
    
   
    Set MasterWorkbook = Nothing
    Set SourceWorkbook = Nothing
    Set SourceWorksheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

i have tried using Range but still facing same issue

Comment: Is there a question? It seems like the answer is your title?

Comment: In your case, it'd be easier using a normal for loop, i.e. `For i = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)` than for each which requires objects. Or like CLR mentions, just have both as Variants. You should already be getting a type mismatch since Array() doesn't give a string array, just fyi.

Comment: Put the `For Each` loop inside the `Do While` loop and then each workbook is opened only once rather than 5 times.